# WPF binding: Doing a temperature converter app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm doing a little app that basically has 2 text boxes. You'll enter Fahrenheit into TextBoxA and Celsius into TextBoxB.

As the text changes in TextBoxA I want the equivalent Celsius value to be displayed in TextBoxB and vice versa.

I can come up with a solution pretty easy for this but i'm trying to be a little clever.

Is there a way to do it all in Xaml except for a Convert class that does the maths? So basically I want the TextChanged event of one textBox to pass in it's value into a Converter class that is evaluated and sent to the other TextBox and visa versa.

Anyone know how I can achieve this ... and if it's possible at all?

Comment: I can't get it. Do you wish to accomplish the task _with_ or _without_ a converter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextBox x:Name="Celsius" />
<Textbox x:Name="Fahrenheit" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Celsius, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource CelsiusToFahrenheitConverter}}" />
```

When you update C, F will get the value and convert it. When you update F, it will convert back to C and push the value to the Celcius textbox.

Comment: Hi Jay. If I use only one convert how do I know if the value to be converted is Celsius or Fahrenheit?

Comment: @Bob An `IValueConverter` has both `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods. So, in my example above, there is a `CelsiusToFahrenheitConverter`. You would implement this to go from C to F in `Convert()` and F to C in `ConvertBack`. The `TwoWay` binding in the Fahrenheit `TextBox` will call `Covert()` when it gets a value from the Celsius `TextBox`, and call `ConvertBack()` when it pushes a value to the Celsius `TextBox`.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks Jay. I now got it working with kent's example although I would prefer to do it your way i.e. with only 1 converter. Using 1 converter, when the text of the top textBox changes the bottom one also changes just fine but I actually have to click out of the botton TextBox, after i change the text, for the top textBox to update. Do you know what I can do about that? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bob You can add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the binding. The default for a `TextBox` is `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox x:Name="CelcuiusTextBox" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=FahrenheitTextBox, Converter={StaticResource FahrenheitToCelciusConverter}}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="FahrenheitTextBox" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=CelciusTextBox, Converter={StaticResource CelciusToFahrenheitConverter}}"/>
```

Assumes the existence of two distinct converters. Of course, you could write a single converter that can be put in a different mode to convert either from or to celcius.

Comment: A single converter is sufficient if you bind just one `TextBox`, but do it `TwoWay`.

Comment: Hi Kent. It sort of works but when one text box updates the other then the converter is triggered again and it bounces around. Can you think of a way to get around this?